# Sorting by birthday date my friend list in Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api, sorting, friend

I'm creating my own application to show forthcoming friend's birthday. I have a permission to get this dates from facebook and i'm displaying all my friends with their date of birth on my site. My only question is how to display ie. first 10 forthcoming birthdays? i'm using $facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=10) but have not idea how to sort them. Anyone help? Which code should i try to sort them? some facebook api code or php code. if php then maybe you have some tips how to do this.Cheers!

Comment: Check this for order by issue in fql: [CLICK HERE](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=25354)

Comment: isn't this for old api? posts are 'bout 4 years ago so maybe their isn't reliable. but i have some idea and if i got something i will share here to inform you. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've resolve the problem by myself. quite simple solutions... maybe too simple but works perfect. That's my code. maybe it help someone in future ;)

```
$fql_n    = "SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strlen(birthday_date) != 0 ORDER BY birthday_date";

    $parame  =   array(
           'method'     => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql_n,
          'callback'    => ''
    );
    $fqlResultt   =   $facebook->api($parame);
    $ile_dat = 0;

    $miesiace_slownie = array("01" => "jan", "02" => "feb", "03" => "mar", "04" => "apr", "05" => "may", "06" => "jun", "07" => "jul", "08" => "aug", "09" => "sep", "10" => "oct", "11" => "nov", "12" => "dec");
    if($fqlResultt){
        foreach($fqlResultt as $ress){
            $data = date("m/d");
            list($fb_m,$fb_d) = explode("/", $ress['birthday_date']);
            $fb_date = $fb_m."/".$fb_d;
            if($data<=$fb_date) { ?>
                <div class="fb_birthday_fr">
                    <span class="fb_brt_day"><?php echo $fb_d . ' ' . $miesiace_slownie[$fb_m]; ?></span>
                    <span class="fb_brt_fr"><?php echo $ress['name']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php
                $ile_dat++;
                if($ile_dat == 6) break;
            }


        }
    }
```

$miesiace_slownie is a array that's convert month data from facebook into local language type.

cheers and many thanks ^Love Sharma for given help. Beer for you ;)

Comment: @Love Sharma i'm new in stockoverflow. is this a rate? if so where i give a +1 ;)

Comment: Leave that... :) no prob... you dont have enough points to do that... :D

Answer (score 3):

Try This to make it work like you mentioned:

```
$friends = json_decode($facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=birthday'));
$friends_birth = array();
foreach($friends->data as $value){
  if(isset($value->birthday->)){
    $dt = split("/",$value->birthday);
    $friends_birth[$value->id] = mktime(0,0,0,$dt[0],$dt[1], date("y"));
  }
}
asort($friends_birth);
echo print_r($friends_birth);
```

This will sort friends in birthday wise... now you can use this data for further logic

Comment: I try your code. but it display error thats "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string" whatever that means (i don't really know). when i delete the json_decode() from my $facebook->api(/me/friends) and add to "friends?limi=5&fields=birthday" it display 5 random people. i think "random" because their birthday's not the forthcoming. Where the error? Many thanks for help, but i need more ;) Waiting for your response. cheers "love sharma"

Comment: What output you are getting after removing json_decode... can you post it... thanx

Comment: Code updated up.. Please try that again... :) and what output is giving please post that too...

Comment: the error is still the same:   Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/mydomain_path/konekt/facebook_connect.php on line 49

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mydomain_path/konekt/facebook_connect.php on line 51
Array ( ) 1

Comment: yes, first of all i don't know if it's your mistake but first error is that: "if(isset($value->birthday->)){". the if ends with ->. it's correct? when i delete this -> next error is wrong foreach: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I'm really greatful for your help. Waiting for your response. Cheers

Comment: yeah that was typo mistake... but can you tell me what's value of $friends?

Comment: when i delete json_decode and "->" from if than i get this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path/facebook_connect.php on line 51
Array ( ) 1  that's all. How can i display value of $friends? Than i will paste you that value, but now i don't know how to display.

Comment: remove everything and just try: `$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=birthday'); echo $friends;` If this itself is not working then `$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); echo $friends;` if both now working then its problem of existing sdk.

Comment: douh! both lines display "Array", so as you said i must "upgrade" my facebook.php library file?!

Comment: means empty array? no friends?

Comment: both line display just "Array" word

Comment: just in case your question: yes, i'm logged in because above the code i'm displaying my name and my date of birth. so i don't know where's the problem. maybe the sdk refresh may help. try this?

Comment: wow, where i can make sure that i have it? if not than what you suggest?

Comment: maybe we could try with fql? (heh, i know it's really silly from my side but ... i don't know how to mix up)

Comment: about this openshh... isn't this some server option? i don't have access to control my apache/php/mysql or any server software so i wouldn't be able to activate this one. still count for your help. greetz!

Comment: You can check with latest sdk and more focus on openssh support... :)

Comment: check that with system admin... or just want to confirm.. that.. is any of your request working? using `$facebook->api`

Comment: hey again, i'm using $facebook->api('/me'); and it's showing my name, birthday etc... on the facebook dev forum admin says that via API i can only display data without sort. he's telling me that better way to do this is by some FQL command. What do you think 'bout it?

Comment: Hi one more time. I try figure out something with fql and i made some select query which showing friends who have birthday in selected day. I cant figure it out how to make some time range in the query.
$fql_n    = "SELECT uid, name, birthday FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strlen(birthday) != 0 ORDER BY birthday";